# User registration: How do implement "Confirm password" and "Confirm email"?

Tags: form, registration

I've got a user registration form on my site, using the code from Craft's documentation. How can I get the form working so it asks the user to enter their email address and password twice? Can Craft take care of that or do I need to use client-side JS validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you should let JavaScript take care of. Craft does not check a 'second' email or password field, so you should make sure the two field values are identical before posting the values to Craft's controller.

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is interested in confirming passwords still, I have wrote a plugin which does just this, it doesn't rely on it's own controller either so there is no bypassing of Crafts own workings :)

https://github.com/alecritson/Craft-Password-Confirm

All you need to do is add a `passwordConfirm` field to your existing form:

```
<input type="password" name="passwordConfirm">
{% if account is defined %}
  {{ account.getErrors('passwordConfirm') }}
{% endif %}
```

It doesn't confirm emails though..sorry

Comment: This is great, and can easily be modified to support confirm email as well!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [letting JavaScript](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2483/57) take care of the extra front-end logic, you could also write a [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that exposes a [controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) that does the extra email and password sameness checks from PHP.

If those are equal, then it would just pass the data off to `craft()->users->saveUser()`, otherwise, return any validation errors back to the template.

Comment: Thanks Brad - will bear that in mind for the future if I ever manage to get my head around OO PHP :)